# How can I add different ids to buttons recyclerview

Tags: java, android, button

My project is based on a recycler view. The layout of each elements is this :

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgview"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="Line 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:text="Line 2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:text="Voir plus" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And I edit it with this :

```
        ArrayList<exempleitem> ExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        ExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 1", "Line 2 ", button2.setId(R.id.hydro) ));
        ExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_airplanemode_active_24, "Line 3", "Line 4 ",button3.setId(R.id.hel)));
        ExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_beach_access_24, "Line 5", "Line 6 ",button4.setId(R.id.lit)));
```

My problem is that I would like to change the ID of each button, and it doesnt work.
I can't think of anything else right now, and I'm quite a begginner.

Comment: Why you need to set different ids to `Button` while you are using recyclerview?

Comment: I would like to set a different event for each of my buttons

Comment: you can still set different click event on your button based on view holder's position just understand how recyclerview will work you will get idea to set different click event

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know how a recyclerview works. It doesn't matter if a button have the same id as another as long as they live in different "cells". Thats the purpose of recyclerviews.

So you have to create a recyclerview adapter and put all the logic in there, the logic will be based on a dataset which is an array probably and your clicks will be based on the position of that array.
You can read more from [Google's official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the ids and if I am not mistaken, you are not even allowed to do that.

I read in the comments that you want to change the event of a button. Try encapsulating the actions of each button click into methods and then setOnClickListener again on the buttons to change their on click action.

Initial Code before changing action

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dosmthA();
        }
    });
```

To change action simply:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dosmthB();
        }
    });
```

You can even create View.OnClickListener() objects and interchange them in the setOnClickListener() method like so:

```
        View.OnClickListener action = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            smth();
        }
    }

    view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewHolder and RecyclerView Adapter to set Click listener for each view...
If you share me the adapter code snippet I can give you the code...